# type of expression must be boolean

Tags: delphi

i got an error message type of expression my be boolean..how i want to solve this problem

```
function GetModeratedFormName(sSourceModuleName: String) : TForm;  
begin      

    if AdditionalModerator(sSourceModuleName) then exit;  
    if sSourceModuleName = 'frmCI' then
        RESULT := frmCI;
end;
```

Comment: @zizil, Delphi shows you exactly on what line of code that error occurs. Next time look very closely to that line, and if you need to ask a question about the the error message, mark the line with a comment in your question.

Answer (score 5):

@zizil, apparently the problem is wich you `AdditionalModerator` function does not return a `boolean` type.

you must write something like this

```
 function AdditionalModerator(Param1:String) : Boolean;
 begin
   // your code goes hee
 end;
```

Comment: Even then zizil would get a "Return value of function 'function' might be undefined"  warning, as result will not be set in AdditionalModerator returns true.